# How do I fix my arraylist for my shoppingList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am fairly new to code and got stuck on fixing part of my code and don't see the issue. The first class is the ADT class and the second one is the ArrayList Class being implemented. In the shoppingListArrayList class, I need to complete remove(), find() and containing() methods so they can be tested any help would be great.

```java
package Shopping;

import DataStructures.*;

/**
 * 
 */
public interface ShoppingListADT {
    
    /**
     * Method to add a new entry. Only new entries can be added. Combines 
     * quantities if entry already exists.
     *
     * @param entry the entry to be added
     */
    public void add(Grocery entry);
    
    /**
     * Method to remove an entry.
     *
     * @param ent to be removed
     * @return true when entry was removed
     */
    public boolean remove(Grocery ent);
    
    /**
     * Method to find an entry.
     *
     * @param index to find
     * @return the entry if found
     * @throws Exceptions.EmptyCollectionException
     */
    public Grocery find(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException,
            EmptyCollectionException;
    
    /**
     * Method to locate the index of an entry.
     *
     * @param ent to find the index
     * @return the index of the entry
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if no entry was found
     */
    public int indexOf(Grocery ent) throws ElementNotFoundException;
    
    /**
     * Method to determine whether the object contains an entry.
     *
     * @param ent to find
     * @return true if and only if the entry is found
     */
    public boolean contains(Grocery ent);
    
    /**
     * Gets the size of the collection.
     *
     * @return the size of the collection
     */
    public int size();
    
    /**
     * Gets whether the collection is empty.
     *
     * @return true if and only if the collection is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty();
    
    /**
     * Returns a string representing this object.
     *
     * @return a string representation of this object
     */
    @Override
    public String toString();
}

private ArrayList<Grocery> shoppingList;

public Grocery find(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException,
            EmptyCollectionException {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("ECE - find");
    }

    // check whether or not the input index number is legal
    // for example, < 0 or falls outside of the size
    for(int i = 0;i<this.size();i++)
        if(index <= 0 || index > this.size() ){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("ArrayList - find");
        }
      
    // return the corresponding entry in the shoppingList
    // need to change the return value
    return shoppingList.get(index);
}

public boolean contains(Grocery ent) {
    boolean hasItem = false;

    // go through the shoppingList and try to find the 
    // item in the list. If found, return true.
    for(int i = 0; i < shoppingList.size(); i++){
        if(shoppingList.contains(ent)){
            hasItem = true;
        }
    }
    return hasItem;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `for(int i = 0;i<this.size();i++)` ?

Comment: I was thinking that would iterate through the arraylist

Comment: But you not using the value of `i`.  The value of `index` does not change.

Comment: yeah I see what you mean i gotta go back and do some work on it

Comment: I get the impression that something is wrong with your code but I don't understand what your problem is. You haven't posted a [mcve] so I can't try to reproduce your problem. Is your code not printing something when you think it should? Is it printing something when you think it should not? Is it not throwing an exception when you think it should? I suggest that you [edit] your question and try to post code that causes your problem to occur. No need to post **all** your code, just enough to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion between the object of the class and it's field shoppingList.
In the find() method, when you write

```
if (this.isEmpty())
```

you probably want to check if shoppingList is empty. Writing "this.isEmpty()" you are not referring to the shoppingList, but the whole class instance. Write instead

```
if (shoppingList.isEmpty())
```

to have your expected behaviour.

The for cycle not required. Notice that the variable "i" is never used in the statement inside the block: then it's not needed.
You only need an if:

```
if(index <= 0 || index > shoppingList.size() ){
  /// throw exception
}
```

The contains() method is ok.

In the future, consider about pasting the whole file. We could see the class name and structure (i expect it to be some sort of collection, but not sure) and other useful stuff. This would help to give a more precise answer.